# Jenkins Javascript Path Failure

Tags: node.js, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I'm building a small test framework running Mocha + WebDriverIO via Jenkins. For some reason, the relative path isn't showing up as expected. As a result, fs.js is throwing an error:

> Error:
>
> > Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\workspaces\nodejstest\jenkins\JENKINS_HOME\jobs\browse_test\workspace\login.js'

The path should be: 'C:\workspaces\nodejstest\login.js' (the absolute location of the executed script). Anybody, have any insight as to why the directory path is wrong even though I'm executing the script from the same directory, NOT the Jenkins workspace directory as the error states. When I run it from the cli, it works fine. Weird.

Test Script (run_test.js):

```
var common      = require('./common/common.js'), // INCLUDES FS LIBRARY
    scriptList  = ['login', 'browse_price_ascending'];

// ITERATE THROUGH SCRIPT NAMES AND EXECUTE
for(var currentScript in scriptList){

    // BUILD SCRIPT PATH
    var scriptPath = './' + scriptList[currentScript] + '.js';

    // EVAL IS NOT ALWAYS EVIL ;)
    eval(common.fs.readFile(scriptPath) + '');

}
```

Start Jenkins (run.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
export JENKINS_HOME=./jenkins/JENKINS_HOME
java -jar ./jenkins/jenkins.war
```

Jenkins Job:

```
mocha $JENKINS_HOME/../../run_test.js --brand=IBSD --country=UK --env=PROD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jenkins, the job's workspace is treated as the current directory. Irrespective of whether you called the *parent* (`$JENKINS_HOME/../../run_test.js`) script by specifying the relative path w.r.t Jenkins, any path specified *within* the script will be treated relative to the Jenkins' job's workspace. So, to resolve your issue, just specify the relative path to *login.js* in your run_test.js script.

If you do not want to move the *login.js* script from your existing location to Jenkins workspace, then you will have to specify the relative path to the file w.r.t Jenkins' job's workspace. However, if you want to make it flexible enough to work both ways i.e., through command line and Jenkins, then you can try any of these approach:

- In your parent script, you can check whether any Jenkins environment variable (such as `JOB_NAME`) is set. The purpose is to check whether your script is running as part of some Jenkins job. If yes, then change the path of *login.js* in your parent script to relative path w.r.t job's workspace.

  ```
  path_to_login.js = default_location

  if (jenkins_env_variable is set) {
     path_to_login.js = ../../../../../../login.js
  }
  ```
- Just like other arguments (`--brand=IBSD --country=UK --env=PROD`) that you are passing to your parent script, you can pass one (such as --jenkins=yes) for checking whether the script is running through Jenkins or command line.

  ```
  path_to_login.js = default_location

  if (jenkins_arg_passed is yes) {
     path_to_login.js=../../../../../../login.js
  }
  ```

Comment: Great. So if I understand correctly, you're saying I should climb UP to the correct folder from within the script. If so, is there no way around this? I'd like to have the option to run the script from the command line as well as Jenkins on an as needed basis.

Comment: Great workaround. I kind of feel dumb for not thinking of it myself haha. Thanks a lot!